# How to make angular.js $http.post send an object with fields that are undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to use angular $http.post method to send an updated object to a node.js backend that uses mongoose.

I have a use-case that a user can make a field undefined, which is ok and should eventually make the mongoose to unset that field from the mongo document.

The problem is that angular.js $http.post actually just does not send any fields that their value is undefined.

This is my line for example:

```
return $http.post(`/api/update`, {
                field1: 1,
                field2: 'hey',
                field3: undefined
            });
```

If i then take a look using the developer tools, i will see that the sent object only contains the 2 first fields.

What should i do to make $http send also fields that are undefined?

Comment: why don't you pass `field3: ''` instead of undefined ? An empty string instead of `undefined ?

Comment: because mongoose will not handle '' the same as undefined.
undefined will make mongoose unset the field while '' won't because the field is a reference to another object

Comment: `undefined` is something related to javascript, which means the identifier is not declared. So when you send undefined, it has to be converted to a common base which is angular doing by removing it from the object being sent as you explicitly mention that `field3` is undefined. The scenario you are trying to do `should be handled on server side` where if a particular `field` is not present, then send it as `undefined` to mongoose. you can't do much from the client side for your scenario.

Comment: Have you tried sending a `null` instead of `undefined`? It may not make mongoose unset the field value, but it would certainly be better than using empty string to detect the condition, and unset the value manually on the server as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is not part of JSON. According to [json.org](http://json.org/), valid value type of JSON is: `string`, `number`, `object`, `array`, `true`, `false` and `null`, no `undefined`.

However, if you really want to send `undefined` value to backend, you can override `JSON.stringify`, as Angular's `$http.post` eventually use `JSON.stringify` to transform JavaScript object in request data (please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583637/707451 for code trace):

```
let oldStringify = JSON.stringify;
let newStringify = function(obj) {
  let varsOfUndefined = [];
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] === undefined) {
      varsOfUndefined.push(k);
    }
  }

  let str = oldStringify(obj);
  if (varsOfUndefined.length === 0) {
    return str;
  }

  str = str.substr(0, str.length-1);
  for (let v of varsOfUndefined) {
    str = str + ',"' + v + '":undefined';
  }
  str = str + '}';
  return str;
};

// when send request using $http.post
JSON.stringify = newStringify;
let o = {
  x: 42,
  y: 'ui',
  z: undefined,
  d: 'ppp'
};
$http.post('/api/temp', o);

// revert to original JSON.stringify
setTimeout(function() {
  JSON.stringify = oldStringify;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}, 0);
```

In this way, the request payload would be:

```
{"x":42,"y":"ui","d":"ppp","z":undefined}
```

Please note: in backend, you need to define corresponding `newParse` function, `JSON.parse` cannot be used directly to parse the above string.