# angularjs 1.x: send {'key' : undefined} with $http.post

Tags: angularjs, http

My requirement is that I want to be able to send an object like `{title: "test", price: undefined}` from my angular-app via $http.post to my nodejs app (to be able to delete the price key via Mongoose update in my mongoDB).

Problem:

Code extract

```
console.log(object)
$http.post(url, object)
```

1. In the console, I see: `{title: "test", price: undefined}`
2. My request payload contains `{title: "test"}`

==> Why doesn't my payload contain the full object? How can I add the price: undefined in my payload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When HTTP request `Content-Type` is `application/json` and the payload object contains `undefined` as some fields' value, those fields will be removed. Otherwise, server side program won't be able to parse the JSON successfully -- an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position ...` will happen (the token `u` is just the "u" of "undefined").

This is not an Angular specific  behaviour, all HTTP requests should have this logic.

---

What happens in Angular's `$http.post`?

In Angular, all request data will be transformed. When the data is JSON, `toJSON` (which equals to `angular.toJson`) will be invoked to do the job ([source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js)):

```
transformRequest: [function(d) {
  return isObject(d) && !isFile(d) && !isBlob(d) && !isFormData(d) ? toJson(d) : d;
}]
```

The `toJson()` function is just a proxy to `JSON.stringify` ([source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js)):

```
function toJson(obj, pretty) {
  if (isUndefined(obj)) return undefined;
  if (!isNumber(pretty)) {
    pretty = pretty ? 2 : null;
  }
  return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty);
}
```

In [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either **omitted (when it is found in an object)** or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contain it because it is `undefined`. Undefined vars are removed from the request. You will just have to know, server-side that if the variable is not included, that you should delete it. Typically you want to use the `PUT` verb for updating a record, vs `POST` for creating a new record.

You could send an empty string or a boolean, or something special, so that you will know in your node app to delete the key.

Comment: Ok, so the best way is to change the undefined value into some stringvalue --> In my node app I can then delete all the keys with this value...
(I will also change post into put ;-))